# How to present XAML page in DirectX UWP app

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

I have a UWP C++ app which was ported from old good DirectX PC game. It does not use XAML stuff at all. There is a class `Direct3DApplicationSource` which implements `Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkViewSource` interface and everything is initialized as simple as

```
[Platform::MTAThread]
int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^)
{
    auto direct3DApplicationSource = ref new Direct3DApplicationSource();
    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::Run(direct3DApplicationSource);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I need to add a video player functionality into the app. I learned that the simplest way is to use [MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement?view=winrt-19041) which presents video player with play/stop/pause UI.

In order to implement it, I need to add sort of XAML page to my app like this:

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Current->Content = myVideoPlayerFrame;
```

But in my case `Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Current == nullptr` because as I mentioned the app is XAML-free initially.

Does anybody has an idea how to "push" XAML page into the DirectX app and then pop it back?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think app it's possible to do that however you can render DirectX content in a XAML app using [SwapChainPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel?view=winrt-19041).